# Programmatically scroll UIScrollView so UILabel is just below navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIScrollView that contains various blocks of buttons, textfields and labels.

There is a UILabel heading the second block. When I tap a button beside it, I wish to programmatically scroll so this label is at the top left of the screen, just below the navigation bar.

I can use the setContentOffset function to do this programmatically, but I can't work out how to programmatically get the value for y. As the top block can expand or contract based on user input I need to get this value programmatically. How do I get the correct value of y for my label?

```
let myLabelTopYPoint = ??!
```

I played around with the following two lines but neither gave what I wanted...

```
let myLabelTopYPoint = myLabel.convert(myLabel.center, to: self.view).y

let myLabelTopYPoint = myLabel.frame.maxY
```

(Applying the below with a manually chosen y of 200 works in the meantime for most user inputs, but is not satisfactory)

```
myScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: myLabelTopYPoint), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get y position of your label in scroll view like this:

```
let myLabelTopYPoint = yourScrollView.convert(myLabel.frame, to: yourScrollView).minY
```

Comment: Thanks, but that always gives me "0" - I need the point relative to the navigation bar rather than to itself. Unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately again myLabel.frame gives 0,0 so scrolls to the top of the page. Thanks for trying

Comment: Didn't you forget to use yourScrollView.convert instead of view.convert?

Comment: Seems as a correct answer to me. Or may be your scrollView's top is constrained to the top of the screen instead of navigation bar.

Comment: I think you're right; I have my label inside a stackView inside another stackView and I think that is interfering. Appreciate your help